# How can I decorate a "callable" class with a class decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, callable

I'm looking to decorate a "callable" class (one that has the `__call__` method defined), so that I can start a background service before `__init__` is called and manipulate the arguments passed before it itself is called to include the details of the service that's been started.

So, for example:

```
@init_service # starts service on port 5432
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, port=9876):
    # init here. 'port' should now be `5432` instead of the original `9876`

  def __call__(self):
    # calls the background service here, using port `5432`

func = Foo(port=9876)
...
result = func()
```

The class `init_service` would have a class attribute with the port number, so that later on the service can be shut-down.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the class being callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to patch the `__init__` method; the fact that there is a `__call__` method as well makes no odds here.

You'd normally decorate the *`__init__` method* instead, using a regular (function) decorator; if you *have* to use a class decorator, then use one that subclasses the decorated class:

```
def init_service(cls):
    class InitService(cls):
        def __init__(self, port='ignored'):
            super(InitService).__init__(5432)

    return InitService
```

Comment: Is there any way I can define the class outside the `init_service` function (it's rather large because of the service init methods) and then redefine which object it inherits from within the `init_service` func?

Comment: @unpluggd: You need a dynamic class that defines the inheritance. That can be a wrapper class that just does `class WrapperInitService(RealInitServiceClass, cls)`, where `WrapperInitService` is outside the decorator. That has some caveats (mostly to do with having to use `super()` for anything you override) but it should just work otherwise.